# Skin effect and mag field distribution inside an electric conductor

Tags: power, electromagnetism, electrical, magnetic-flux, skin-effect

Magnetic field inside a current carrying conductor[image]
Suppose I took a circular current strip in a current carrying wire. At the centre I have marked the directions of magnetic field due to four points 1,2,3,4 in the strip, and as the direction are opposite they cancel each other. Then how can flux linkage be maximum at the centre if instead they are cancelling each other.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you assuming that skin effect means current flux is higher in the centre? If so: this is wrong. Current flux is higher near the surface and in addition this effect only manifests itself with AC current. Skin depth (at surface) is a function of frequency.

Also, you're drawing flux lines in the conductor as if it was in air. In an ideal conductor, magnetic flux is constant

Comment: No I read that Faraday induced flux linkage is more in the centre, hence more opposition, hence less current or less resultant flux in the centre. But it seems to me that when flux itself is zero at the centre, how can there be em induction opposing? And your last line, is my assumption wrong?? I took a circular strip and drew the directions due to four points on strip. Please clarify. Thanks for the reply.:)